# Documentation for the exceptions thrown by DDTek.Sybase common database methods

Tags: c#, .net, sybase

Is there any link where I can find the documentation for the exceptions thrown by DDTek.Sybase common database methods like ExecuteScalar ,SybaseAdapter.Fill etc.

I am looking for documentations like the following documentation of Microsoft for the [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

Actually otherwise I have to handle the exception by using the Exception class as I do not know which exceptions are thrown by the concerned method.

Comment: Have  you checked the DataDirect site?  http://www.progress.com

Comment: Tried to search in google..but there was not much info regarding this...looked in progress.com also..but could not find much...